# Intelligent plural always intelligent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, grammar

Ruby on rails uses singular and plural conventions for model, view and controller names. This is very good, since one might have a model called `user` and a controller called `users`. This work with almost every word, such as user(s), tree(s), book(s), so every word that just has an s to form the plural.

However, what about words that do not just need an s to form the plural, such as words ending with the letter "y"? E.g., city and cities? Does rails know the difference or would I need to write `city` and `citys`, even though it is grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rails knows a lot of plurals. It can handle "city," for example:

```
1.9.2p318 :001 > "city".pluralize
 => "cities" 
1.9.2p318 :002 > "cities".singular
 => "city"
```

However, you may find plurals it doesn't know, and won't be learning. See the documentation for `ActiveSupport::Inflector`

> The Rails core team has stated patches for the inflections library
>   will not be accepted in order to avoid breaking legacy applications
>   which may be relying on errant inflections. If you discover an
>   incorrect inflection and require it for your application, you’ll need
>   to correct it yourself (explained below).

How do you correct it yourself? In `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. For example:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(.*)(l)ens$/i, '\1\2enses'
end
```

See again the docs for [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) for more on how to teach rails new inflections.

Comment: That explains it very well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of common ones, it knows how to handle it pretty well. You can try this yourself in IRB by doing the following:

```
require 'active_support/all'
ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize("city")
```

And you'll get back a string with the value "cities". You can also add and adjust inflections by following the steps listed in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`